# What weapons can be silenced and when do they unlock?

Tags: far-cry-4

I'm playing Far Cry 4 on PC, and I like to go for a silent approach whenever possible. I already got the Recurve Bow as one weapon, and crafted up to level 3 holster.

The problem is that 10 arrows really is not that much. I'd also like to have a silenced sidearm. I understand that there are also silenced sniper rifles, and maybe other silenceable guns.

Which weapons can be silenced, and when do they unlock?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I discovered almost by accident that one of the earliest unlockable weapons that supports a silencer is the one you get as a redemption reward from Uplay, the A.J.M. 9 which has references to Far Cry Blood Dragon and Robocop.

While creating this question, I went on another search and I found http://www.supercheats.com/far-cry-4/walkthrough/weapons-catalog.

the list of suppressable weapons is:

- F1 (14 towers);
- MS16 (10 towers);
- 6P9 (story reward);
- A99 (story reward);
- A.J.M. 9 (30 Uplay points);
- M-700 (7 towers);
- SA-50 (story reward);
- Z93 (Story reward);
- BZ19 (Story reward);
- MP5 (12 towers);
- Vector .45 ACP (story reward);

In addition, the weapons from hd's answer also can be silenced.

Answer (score 6):

#### DLC Exclusives

- Harpoon gun is exclusive to the Hurk's Redemption DLC.

#### Signature Weapons

- [Bushman](http://farcry.wikia.com/wiki/Bushman) - Available after reaching the rank 10 of the Shanath Arena
- [HS77](https://farcry.fandom.com/wiki/M-712#HS77_) - Available after completing 2 Hunting: Control quests
- [Predator](https://farcry.fandom.com/wiki/M-700#M-700_.22Predator.22_) - Available after completing 4 armed escort quests.
- [Stinger](https://farcry.fandom.com/wiki/Skorpion#Signature_Version) - Available after destroying 2 Pagan's Wrath convoys.
- [Shredder](https://farcry.fandom.com/wiki/Vector_.45_ACP#Far_Cry_4) - Available after reaching Karma level 6.
- [Trooper](https://farcry.fandom.com/wiki/MS16#MS16_Trooper_) - Available after collecting 20 masks of Yalung.
- [Warrior](https://farcry.fandom.com/wiki/AK-47/FC4#Warrior_) - Available after hijacking 2 Royal cargo trucks.

Comment: I'm also wondering about those you get for liberating radio towers, more specifically the earliest ones to unlock.

Comment: From a post on [gamefaqs](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/795264-far-cry-4/70611396) (post#7), it could be M700 sniper rifle by liberating radio towers.

Comment: And what about sidearms?

Comment: That would be the Scorpion and M-712 - unlock criteria is mentioned above.

Comment: Weird, I read on http://www.twinfinite.net/2014/11/20/far-cry-4-weapon-guide/ that, for example, the 6P9 is also silenceable.

Comment: @NateKerkhofs Ah I may have missed that one, my bad.

Comment: I also doubt that the only weapons that can be silenced are a handful of signature weapons. The problem is that, in order to see what weapons are silenceable, you need to unlock it first.

Answer (score 0):

I would definitely recommend the 6p9 with suppressor and extended mags. It will 1tap any light enemy (hunter, grunt, light flamer, bezerker) Also definitely run the z93 with suppressor, variable zoom and extended mags. It will 1 shot (to the head) heavy enemies (Heavy Gunner, Heavy Flame Trooper) I also run the p416 (I’m level 9 in the arena) with a marksman soft and extended mags for when I need to go loud. I also have the recurve now for if I need to kill animals.

Answer (score -1):

Learn to use the bow.

The Recurve bow is the best stealth weapon by far as it is the most silent and it doesn't take much to get. Practice on hitting something from a slight distance. Honestly I bought it right after going down the zipline on the first bell tower mission and talked to the trading guy.

If you REALLY want a silenced gun, pick up the AJM 9 as a uplay reward, and get the silencer and extended mag on it (No need for the red dot sight). My tactic is always picking up a bow and the AJM 9 and carefully clear each area of whatever I'm doing.

Comment: refrain from the profanity, we have to come and clean it up. Thanks